# Nested Classes with properties - How do i use the value of properties of the first nest in the `Set` for the second

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, object

*Important info for anyone looking at this with a similar query*

The simple answer is you can't - the answer from Plutonix below explains why hence it is marked as an answer

*Original Question*

Drawn a blank after spending 1/2 a day Googling this!

I have the following class:

```
Public Class TestClass

    Dim _nestedProperty As New NestedProperty()

    Private Shared Item As String

    Public Property Nest1a() As NestedProperty
        Get
            Return _nestedProperty
        End Get
        Set(Value As NestedProperty)

        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Nest1b() As NestedProperty
        Get
            Return _nestedProperty
        End Get
        Set(Value As NestedProperty)

        End Set
    End Property

    Public Class NestedClass

        Property Nest2a As String
            Get
                Return sub1()
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                'the first value in sub 2 needs to be the name of the Nest1 property
                sub2([how do i get this value],value)
            End Set
        End Property
        Property Nest2b As String
            Get
                Return sub1()
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                'the first value in sub 2 needs to be the name of the Nest1 property
                sub2([how do i get this value],value)
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class

    Shared Function sub1()

    End Function

    Shared Sub sub2(Nest1 As String, Value As String)

    End Sub 
End Class
```

In reality there are many properties in the first nest and i want to know which one is 'calling' the second nest.

i.e. if i use `TestClass.Nest1a.Nest2a = "abc"`, When calling `Sub2` from the `Set` of `Nest2a` I need to pass in `"Nest1a"` instead of `[how do i get this value]`.

I tried setting the 'Item' object in the `Set` of the first nest but it doesn't work!

From the main form i am calling this class by the following code:

```
Dim TC As New TestClass
TC.Nest1.Nest2a = "xyz"
'lots more code
TC.Nest1.Nest2b = "abc"
```

I do NOT want to create a new instance of `TestClass` each time i use it!

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Based on sample codes above (the 2nd code block), what do you expect to get in place of `[how do i get this value]`?

Comment: `[how do i get this value]` is there several times.  for the TestClass.Sub2, its just `TestClass.Sub2` but as a sub there is no value to 'get'.  For the actual properties, see below. `TC.Nest1.Nest2a = "xyz"` is invalid because they are not nested props - Nest2a belongs to a different class.

Comment: @Plutonix It seems that OP want to get a string containing the property name in place of `[how do i get this value]` (it should be "Nest1a" or "Nest1b" in the example in question). I don't think it is possible to do that.

Comment: @Plutonix OK - perhaps i should be asking how do i use nested props? from my research this is what i thought i was doing! - I am just looking at you answer now.

Comment: @har07 I agree. `NestedProperty` is not a property at all but a Class, so Nest2a has nothing to do with the parent and has no awareness of it without an instance reference.

Comment: Apologies Nested Property was the wrong name for the class - @har07 has got what i want, i want to be able to pass in a string to the second nest (i am OK with hard coding this ie i am not looking for property.name but to be able to pass in "Nest1a").

Comment: the child class is just a class, use it like you would any other, **except** pass it a parent reference if you want the child to access parent properties.  the parent can access child props once an instance is created.  (See below where both are demonstrated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested classes, not properties. The nested class needs to have a reference to the parent class, typically passed in the constructor

```
Class Parent 
   Private myChild As Foo

   Public | Private | Friend Class Foo
       private myPArent As Parent

       Public Sub New(p as Parent)
          myParent = p
       End Sub

       ' now the nested class has a reference to the parent
       Public Function xyz As Integer
           Return myParent.SomeFunction * 2
       End Function
       ...
   End Class

   ' parent using child props:
    Public Function GetFoo As integer
       return myChild.Somthing
    End Function
    ...
End Class
```

For the SHARED subs you dont need a ref:

```
Parent.Sub2
```

But what can be done in them is slightly limited (no reference or use of instance data).  Depending on the actual nature of the props and such inheritance is sometimes an alternative.  The more likely you are to need to create Parent.Child class instances elsewhere, the more you should consider inheritance.

Interfaces might be another alternative.

**EDIT**

Nested classes are very often private and used as 'helper' classes for the parent.  But if they are public, they can be created:

```
Dim p As New ParentFoo
Dim c As New ParentFoo.ChildBar
```

As a private helper class, the parent can simply use the child to provide the result:

```
Dim xyz As Integer = p.BarCount
```

inside the parent class:

```
' the parent class may know nothing about Bars
' and uses a helper to manage them:
Public Function BarCount As Integer
    return myChild.BarCount
End Function
```

**IF** the parent class exposes the child reference, you can do something similar to what you want:

```
Public Property ChildFoo As Foo
  Get
     Return myChildFoo
  End Get
```

Now you can do `p.ChildFoo.BarCount`.  But that simply begs the question `if the nested class is to be consumed externally, why is it nested?`  External code can set myChild to nothing, set props directly and potentially break the parent class as well!

Comment: Thanks for this - definitely helps to understand where i am going wrong - so is there no way of using `p.childbar.BarCount`?

Comment: If the child reference is exposed as a property you can do that - See edit

Comment: @OSKM one other point: for external code to reference nested classes directly means it has to know which services are provided by the parent and which by the child(ren).  That makes for messy code and all the more reason to rethink the direction you are going in.  HTH

Comment: Thanks for this, in my particular case the external code will never reference services by the parent only child(ren) services. - thanks to your answer i have found a way of doing what i need, the reasoning behind it is too long to put on here!